# How to generate solutions with a template?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having a bit of trouble here.

I want to be able to generate a C# project (and solution) (let's say a C# Console Application) using a template similar to the ones VS2010 uses.
Basically I want to have a method GenerateConsoleApplication which does just that. But since I will need to generate several of these, I want to use a template to populate the Main method of the program.cs class which will be generated alongside the .csproj and app.xml files.

```
public void GenerateConsoleApplication()
{
    var projectName = "MyConsoleApplication";
    var projectLocation = "C:\temp";

    // what goes here so that it creates a solution Visual Studio that I could use ?
}
```

I looked up the project template used by VS2010 to generate a C# Console Application and am thinking I could modify it to suit my needs. But I have no idea what I would need to write (code wise) to use the said template and generate all the files of the new solution.
Does anyone know how to do it ? Or if it is even possible ?

I know I could just write the csproj file and the others but I think a template would allow changes more easily.

Comment: Have you read through the [`How to: Create Project Templates`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx) document on MSDN? Did you read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188697.aspx) MSDN magazine article on the subject?

Comment: Yes I did. But I am not trying to create a solution template for visual. I want to write a piece of code that will generate the solution.

Comment: Try [Templify](https://github.com/endjin/Templify). [Sharp Architecture](http://sharparchitecture.net/) uses it to generate solutions

Comment: OK found the solution, I'll have to write a parser for my template, and make the subsitution with Regex. Then it's just a matter of writing in a file. Would have been nice to use the same parser as visual, but I don't think that's possible. I'll need to simplify the template too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found what I'll need to do.

The problem boils down to the parsing of the templates files.
Once I get the parser, then I can replace the tags with the appropriate values. I wanted to use Visual Studio's parser to do that, and slightly modify the templates it already uses, but it's not possible.

So one has to write its own parser and use it to generate the files.
Then Regex can be use to replace the tags of the template file with the Regex.Replace(String, String, MatchEvaluator) method.

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent project templates badly (you **are** going to run into trouble using regular expressions to create and/or replace stuff in an XML file, i.e. the .csproj and .sln files) when there are perfectly usable solutions out there? :-)